# azure wcf and mvc under same subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, subdomain

i have my project up and running via Azure with two WebRoles. a MVC project and a WCF. I would like to know if it's possible to have both web applications under same subdomain. is that possible? or will i end up with having 2 subdomains (one subdomain for mvc and one subdomain for wcf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idealy you put each of the projects under different cloud services. Two cloud service, two projects (mvc and wcf). They have two different *.cloudapp.net addresses.

Comment: I would like to map these two into same domain address. instead of having mvc.mydomain.com and wcf.mydomain.com. i prefer xxx.mydomain.com and xxx.mydomain.com/wcf

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. /wcf is a path of the domain. It is not another application. like you upload a file to /images/image.gif it is a path to a simple file. application is more complicated.